# wait in while loop for external variable change or event?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a question/problem with an whileloop

I need to wait until something changes outside the while loop.

Let's say i have this while loop:

```js
window.changeMe = true;
while(window.changeMe){

}
```

now i have these two options:

1. Change the `changeMe` variable via the Console/JavaScript Execution
2. Change the `changeMe` variable via an WebSocket Event

but neither is working, if i change the Variable directly, it is not changed.
If i trigger an WebSocket Event its not getting called.
Maybe its `BLOCKED`.. so is there any other way to change the variable?

I known i can use `await` and its already working that way, but the problem is that these functions with while are called via an Addon
and using many await's looks kinda ugly for the addon creator :(

an system with `setTimeout` & Callbacks are also working but also looks kinda ugly..

Comment: You can not use a while loop. It will lock up the browser. Typically you use an interval. Ideally you fire an event...

Comment: If you have to reside to polling in a loop, then you *have to* use `await` with small delays. Not certain what else you expect.

Comment: You can't. Javascript is single theaded and a synchronous task is never interrupted. Thus, once your code enters the `while` loop it is never interrupted and no other code can run. Read about the JS concurrency model and eventloop here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @epascarello oh yes sorry thats also whats currently working, but calling all functions with an callback, also looks kinda ugly xD

Comment: The only way that I could see this working is with an async generator, but I think you should go with event listeners instead.

Comment: So make it so it looks less ugly. Hard to know what you need exactly to improve the "ugly" code.

Comment: @epascarello yes, theoretically i can inspect the addon code before it gets executed and insert the await before each function that need the await xD ... u think thats a good "solution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Having a infinite while loop will prevent executing any other code from javascript event loop which occupies the main thread.

In order to imitate the same behavior you can implement your own while loop that is friendly to asynchronous events and external code execution. You have to use:

- **tail recursion** in order to minimize the memory footprint,
- **setTimeout** as a mechanism to allow other parts of your code to run asynchronously.

EXAMPLE:

```
window.changeMe = true;

let stop = setTimeout(() => { console.log("External change stop"); window.changeMe = false; }, 4000)

var whileLoop = () => {

  console.log("Inside: ", window.changeMe)
  
  return window.changeMe
    ? setTimeout(() => { whileLoop(); }, 0)
    : false

}

whileLoop()

console.log("Outside: ", window.changeMe)
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qwmosfrd/

Here is a setInterval fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2s6pa1jo/

Promise return value example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0qum6gnf/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, but the problem here will be that i need to call stop `Outside` so it will return to the same problem, for more clarification i am calling "NativeFunctions" outside the browser and i need to know in Js when its done. With Timeout i am already tried that and its working i known. but how written in the comments above. calling functions with many Callbacks also looks kinda ugly.. sorry forgot that to write it in the post..

Comment: So you can change that into a setInterval with a 0 timeout. You have to understand that each of these function calls is a separate entity on the main thread allowing you to do other things in your code. Added a setInterval fiddle that cleans itself.

Comment: uhm yes but lets say your `whileLoop()` returns an value? `var returnValue = whileLoop()` .. in that case it will not work right? because setTimeout or setInterval will leave your whileLoop function and will than not return something

Comment: Yes. In that case you have to use a promise. Look. You're trying to fight the javascript architecture. This is not java or c++. Third fiddle added.

Comment: yes i known xD.. oh working with `then` was something i didn't thought off.. i think thats the best solution between await and callbacks (its the same like callbacks but looks more Js friendly ;)

Comment: Cool! If you think so hit the "Like button" so others can find this answer easier! :D

Comment: A solution to "poll" the value with `setTimeout()` could work (with some undesirable side affects), but it's still a bad design.  Change whatever it is that modifies the value to be event driven.   Fix the architecture rather than hack it.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded. If you have `while (true) {}`, then nothing else outside the `while` loop can change the state of your program. You need to change your approach. You probably want to set up [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead or put this inside an `async` function so you can use `await` to release execution, or some other asynchronous API. But plain vanilla `while () {}` is synchronous and cannot be affected by other things while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `while` loop in that way in nodejs.

Nodejs runs your Javascript in a single thread and the overall architecture of the environment is event driven.  What your `while` loop is doing is a spin loop so while that loop is running, no other events can ever run.  You have to return control back to the event loop before any other events can run.  That means that timers, network events, etc... cannot run while your spin loop is running.  So, in nodejs, this is never the right way to write code.  It will not work.

The one exception could be if there was an `await` inside the loop which would pause the loop and allow other events to run.

So, while this is running:

```
while(window.changeMe){

}
```

No other events can run and thus nothing else gets a chance to change the `changeMe` property.  Thus, this is just an infinite loop that can never complete and nothing else gets a chance to run.

Instead, you want to change your architecture to be event driven so that whatever changes the `changeMe` property emits some sort of event that other code can listen to so it will get notified when a change has occurred.  This can be done by having the specific code that changes the property also notify listeners or it can be done by making the property be a setter method so that method can see that the property is being changed and can fire an event to notify any interested listeners that the value has changed.

Comment: yes i already know that ty, and the event part will not working because i only get notified outside js (via WebSocket or Direct JavaScript execution eg console)

Comment: @DetoxJS - So, if you already know this, then what is your question?  You cannot do it this way.  You have to design it differently to use an event-driven mechanism.

Comment: idn maybe there is an way to get webhook messages with an functions withgout waiting for the event

Comment: @DetoxJS - No.  All messages flow through the event loop and your `while` loop is blocking the event loop.